# C++ error compilation because private member

Tags: c++, scheduler

My main class `Task` has a private member:

```
private:
    Task();
```

I add a derivate class `Scheduler` with herance of class `Task`:

```
class Scheduler : public Task {
    friend class Task;`
```

I create a file `Scheduler.cc` to implement the constructor of class derivate `Scheduler`:

```
Scheduler::Scheduler() {
    //nothing here.
}
```

I try compile with  the constructor `Scheduler` in blank but I received an  compilation error that I am not understanding the relation because my constructor `Scheduler` is in blank:

> `/tmp/PROJETO/T1/booos-t1/lib/Task.h: In constructor ‘BOOOS::Scheduler::Scheduler()’:
>   /tmp/PROJETO/T1/booos-t1/lib/Task.h:41:2: error: ‘BOOOS::Task::Task()’ is private
>   Scheduler.cc:13:22: error: within this context
>   make[1]: ** [Scheduler.o] Erro 1`

I would like understand my problem because I am not trying to access private member of  class Task in my `Scheduler` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Task` is a base class of `Scheduler`,

```
Scheduler::Scheduler() {
  //nothing here.
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Scheduler::Scheduler() : Task() {
  //nothing here.
}
```

Since `Task::Task()` is private, the compiler cannot process that code.

You can put the default constructor of `Task` in `protected` section to get rid of this error. That way, a client cannot create an instance of `Task` using the default constructor but the sub-classes of `Task` can use its default constructor.

```
protected:
      Task();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Task()` is not a `private member`, it's a `private default constructor`.

Your derived class cannot access your `private` default constructor. You need to make it `protected`, or, if you have another costructor available, use this one:

```
class Task
{
public:
    Task( int i );

private:
    Task();
};

Scheduler::Scheduler()
{ // does not compile, equivalent to the next one
}

Scheduler::Scheduler() : Task() 
{ // does not compile
}

Scheduler::Scheduler() : Task(3) 
{ // does compile!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a constructor always calls a constructor ot the parent class. Either explicitly through the initialization list, or implicitly the default constructor.
And here the default constructor of the parent class is private, so ...